# Plone TinyMCE themed preview

Tags: tinymce, plone

is there a "healthy" way to make the TinyMCE-Preview-Button work with plone.app.theming?
Content could be in different workflow_states (private, visible, ...)

For example:
Work on content (http://edit.example.com) -> click TinyMCE Preview-Button -> Live-Preview with themed site (http://www.example.com/)

thanks for suggestions

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this right now but this would be great if implemented!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the question is relevant.

You mix plone.app.theming and multi domains theming.

Plone is not multidomain theming friendly and will not be.

And even if it was (let say throw an addon) you have to build your own tinymce plugin to do that because tinymce is not itself a multidomains tool.

So you will have to build a specific plugin to achieve this.